# Spring boot 3 fail run in java 17

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

My application not run.

Properties of pom file:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <quickcloud.version>2.0.0</quickcloud.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <spring.boot.version>3.0.7</spring.boot.version>
    <org.junit.jupiter>5.9.1</org.junit.jupiter>
    <mockito.junit.jupiter>5.1.1</mockito.junit.jupiter>
    <avro.version>1.11.3</avro.version>
</properties>
```

Log:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.<init>(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:196)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
'void org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.addInitAnnotationType(java.lang.Class)'
```

The calling method's class, org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, was loaded from the following location:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/arlemat/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.11/spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class
```

The called method's class, org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/arlemat/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.11/spring-context-6.0.11.jar!/org/springframework/context/annotation/CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class
```

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: file:/C:/Users/arlemat/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.11/spring-context-6.0.11.jar
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor: file:/C:/Users/arlemat/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.8/spring-beans-6.0.8.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Start in debug mode in InteliJJ.